# Listbox Remove Spaces

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am trying to use this code to remove spaces from a listbox but it is not working

```
Dim word As String() = {" "}
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox5.Items.Count - 1
    For Each Word As String In word
        If ListBox5.Items(i).ToString.Contains(Word) Then
            ListBox5.Items(i) = ListBox5.Items(i).ToString.Replace(Word, String.Empty)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Your code will not compile. `Word` hides `word` in the same block (VB is case insensitive).

Comment: I changed word here I have something different.

Comment: I understand that you had something else there. My point is that you should not post code that does not compile. This can only confuse future visitors.

Comment: Grand grand I will repost the code :
http://pastebin.com/Rcm73tqV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a string array with one value and its static, why?
It seems you could do this simply by coding it like this
scan every item and replace " " with string.empty, 
don't bother checking if it exists, just run the replace statement on every item

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox5.Items.Count - 1    
    ListBox5.Items(i) = ListBox5.Items(i).ToString.Replace(" ", String.Empty)    
Next
```

Comment: Thanks though there are still spaces in the listbox items, can you give an example of it in a working program or something, I must be leaving something out.

Comment: Perhaps it would be simpler if your shared your code to load the listboxes in the first place.

Comment: I did do that.. By the way its information from a webpage to a listbox and the spaces are spaces in the webpage if that helps

Comment: Ok, I do not see your code to load the listbox, I see code that loops through each item in a listbox and tries to update it

Comment: unfortunately, company network policy prevent me from accessing this site

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox5.Items.Count - 1
            ListBox5.Items(i) = ListBox5.Items(i).ToString.Replace(" ", Nothing)
        Next
```

fist we have  to loop through the listbox items. we declared the items from index 0 to the final item index,ie listbox.items.count-1 . this is stored in a variable i. next all the items ,say from 0 to count-1 is replaced.
istBox5.Items(i).ToString.Replace(" ", Nothing) " " indicates a space and'nothing' indicates null.you can also use regex.replace here by importing system.regularexpressions.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the code. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!